# Digital Substitution in CultureInfo for Arabic Hindi numbers

Tags: c#, numbers, arabic, hindi

I want to display Hindi numeric for Arabic culture "ar-EG". It is not totally configured by cultureInfo Digital Substitution/ Number Format APIs.

In "Control Panel -> Region and Language", the format is English(US). It would not be updated to "Arabic(EG)"

In current .net v4.0, is there any solution for me to reach it???

Thanks,

James

Answer (score -1):

Please use Globalization

program.cs run add

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar-EG");
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar-EG");
```

Comment: Thanks Elvin for your information. After setting thread culture, the numeric value is westen number in label. It doesn't work...